# Illegal offset type when assigning Permission into Role in spatie/laravel-permission using UUID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-permission

I have implemented [laravel-permission](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/uuid/) to custom my Model using UUID primary key. Then I created a seeder:

```
$viewemployee = Permission::create(['id' => Str::uuid(), 'name' => 'view employee']);
$A = Role::create(['id' => Str::uuid(), 'name' => 'A']);
```

But, when I'm trying to assign the permission to the role using:

```
$A->givePermissionTo($viewemployee);
```

It shows error like this when I run the seed

> ErrorException
> Illegal offset type
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivot>Table.php:139

Then, I tried another method to assign:

```
$viewemployee->assignRole($A);
```

But, it shows another error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`role_has_permissions`, CONSTRAINT `role_has_permissions_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `role_has_permissions` (`permission_id`, `role_id`) values (8f98272b-cbc3-459b-ab23-fc8fa86dd199, 0))

I have followed the documentation about UUID and Extending correctly, yet I still can't figure it out what I miss so that I can't run my seed.

`role` and `permission` data are successfully inserted, it seems like have a trouble when trying to insert to `role_has_permissions` pivot table.

Here's my migration for `permissions`, `roles` and `role_has_permissions` tables:

```
Schema::create($tableNames['permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->uuid('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('guard_name');
      $table->timestamps();

      $table->primary('id');
});

Schema::create($tableNames['roles'], function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->uuid('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->string('guard_name');
     $table->timestamps();

     $table->primary('id');
});

Schema::create($tableNames['role_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames) {
    $table->uuid('permission_id');
    $table->uuid('role_id');

    $table->foreign('permission_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on($tableNames['permissions'])
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('role_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on($tableNames['roles'])
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id'], 'role_has_permissions_permission_id_role_id_primary');
});
```

Comment: Have the spatie migrations accordingly? Can you share the migrations you are using for the role_has_permissions table?

Comment: @KurtFriars yeah, all migrations ran successfully, and they have `uuid` as primary key instead of bigincrement, i have added my `permissions`, `roles` and `role_has_permissions` migrations at my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `Str::uuid()` to a string `(string)Str::uuid()`

```
$viewemployee = Permission::create(['id' => (string)Str::uuid(), 'name' => 'view employee']);
```

Otherwise ID's `Permission` will be a UUID object instead of a UUID string.

Comment: The SQL in the error message shows the UUID is being sent properly to the database engine.

Comment: @miken32 It does since the `insert` will cast it. But the model will keep the UUID object in the ID since it won't refresh the attributes from the database. But then, when loading the relationship Laravel will expect a string but will get an object.